# How do you make button save form data on a csv file and redirect you to a new page at the same time?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make a button that saves form data on a file and redirects you afterwards,  but although the save function works just fine, the redirection doesn't happen. I've tried only href and formaction so far. Any suggestions?

Paste bin : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4Wcx1wKy)

Thank you for your time reading this !

**the code:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<footer>
<form method="post">
         <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="private_number" checked="checked">
         <label for="html">private_number</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="clieant_number">
          <label for="css">clieant_number</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" maxlength="11" autocomplete="off" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" required >          
          <button type="submit" name="BUY"><i class="arrow right"></i></button>
    </form>
</footer>
<?php
  $numurs = $_POST['fname'];
  $Partners = $_POST['fav_language'];
if ($numurs){
   $f = fopen('numurs.csv', 'w');
   fputcsv($f,  Array($numurs, $Partners));
   fclose($f);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `header()` function for this. Change the PHP part to this

```
<?php
$numurs = $_POST['fname'];
$Partners = $_POST['fav_language'];

if ($numurs){
   $f = fopen('numurs.csv', 'w');
   fputcsv($f,  Array($numurs, $Partners));
   fclose($f);

   header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit;
}
?>
```